# Can a SharePoint 2010 enterprise wiki link to a parent site's object?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wiki

I am building an Enterprise Wiki in SharePoint 2010 for an IT department with several teams. It looks like our scenario would benefit from using sub-sites for each team that is using the enterprise wiki. Common information would be in the parent wiki site, and each team's specific information would be in sub-sites.

The one problem that I am having is that there is a shared list with information in the parent wiki site, but the sub sites can no longer link to it.

When editing pages in the enterprise wiki's sub-sites, is there a way to create a link (using the [[ function) to a list item or page in the parent site?

Comment: I have seen many threads like this one (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sharepointcollaboration/thread/7381c8ca-0ce3-4f01-ac30-ff6fdf1a3a44) but am not trying to create a view or embed the list. I want wiki contributors to be able to type [[ and link directly to items in the parent site's list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this appears to be a big fat no.